# Passing Data to Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a working angular page which displays a bunch of charts, using d3, based on data retrieved from a server via a service.

But I'm curious if there's a better way to pass the data from the service to the directives used to create the chart. Right now I'm doing that via attributes on the directive element. If the dataset is large (e.g., 6 lines to be shown on a line chart, each with 100 or more data points, each having an x and y value) that ends up being a fairly big piece of HTML markup :)

I thought about injecting the service that retrieves and holds the data into the directive. But that ties the directive to that particular service, which makes the directive less useful in other angular apps.

I also thought about holding the data in the parent/page scope, passing the name of that variable to the directive, and then accessing the data itself from within the directive by accessing the parent scope. But again, that ties me to a particular project structure (e.g., data always resides as a variable in the parent scope).

What's best practice? Or, if there isn't a generally accepted best practice, what other approaches do people use?

**More Info**

The data being passed through markup is in the form of objects and arrays. Here's an example of what shows up in the elements tab of the chrome debugger for one of the charts, formatted for clarity.

```
<bar-chart 
    bar-data="{
           'type':'LabelValueChartData',
           'friendly':{
                'vehicles':'Vehicles',
                'timeOfDay':'Time of Day'
           },
           'color':{
                'type':'ColorByFieldValue',
                'defaultColor':'#000000',
                'colors':[
                    {'name':'12:00 AM','color':'#0000CC'},
                    {'name':'12:15 AM','color':'#0000CC'},
                    {'name':'12:30 AM','color':'#0000CC'},
                    {'name':'12:45 AM','color':'#0000CC'},
                    {'name':'1:00 AM','color':'#0000CC'},
                {'name':'1:15 AM','color':'#0000CC'},
                {'name':'1:30 AM','color':'#0000CC'},
                ...
                ]},
       'colorType':'ColorByFieldValue',
       'data':[
               {'seriesName':'vehicles','label':'12:00 AM','value':172},
               {'seriesName':'vehicles','label':'12:15 AM','value':150},
               {'seriesName':'vehicles','label':'12:30 AM','value':158},
               {'seriesName':'vehicles','label':'12:45 AM','value':140},
               {'seriesName':'vehicles','label':'1:00 AM','value':98},
               {'seriesName':'vehicles','label':'1:15 AM','value':104},
               {'seriesName':'vehicles','label':'1:30 AM','value':94},
               {'seriesName':'vehicles','label':'1:45 AM','value':84},
               {'seriesName':'vehicles','label':'2:00 AM','value':64},
               {'seriesName':'vehicles','label':'2:15 AM','value':75},
                ...
               ],
           'valueProps':['vehicles'],
           'labelProp':'timeOfDay',
           'minValue':0,
           'maxValue':445
           }" 
           layout="{
               'type':'TwoAxisChartLayout',
               '$width':null,
               '$height':null,
               '$margin':{
                   'top':10,
                   'left':80,
                   'bottom':100,
                   'right':10
                   },
               '$xAxis':{
                   'type':'XAxis',
                   '$title':null,
                   '$ticks':null,
                   '$tickSpacing':12,
                   '$offset':null,
                   '$anchor':null,
                   '$fraction':0,
                   '$independent':true,
                   'labels':{
                       'type':'Labels',
                       '$dx':'-0.7em',
                       '$dy':'0.7em', 
                       '$anchor':'end',
                       '$rotate':-45,
                       'formatter':{
                           'type':'NumberFormatter',
                           '$sigDigits':2,
                           '$negParens':true,
                           '$commas':true
                       }
                   } 
               },
               '$yAxis':{
                   'type':'YAxis',
                   '$title':'Vehicles',
                   '$ticks':5,
                   '$tickSpacing':null,
                   '$offset':'-5em',
                   '$anchor':'middle',
                   '$fraction':0.5,
                   '$independent':false,
                   'labels':{
                       'type':'Labels',
                       '$dx':null,
                       '$dy':'.4em',
                       '$anchor':'end',
                       '$rotate':null,
                       'formatter':{
                           'type':'NumberFormatter',
                           '$sigDigits':2,
                           '$negParens':true,
                           '$commas':true
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }" 
           class="ng-isolate-scope">
</bar-chart>
```

This is after angular modifies the original markup based on various scoped variable values. The original markup is this:

```
<bar-chart bar-data="{{vehiclesByTimeOfDay}}"
           layout="{{vehiclesByTimeOfDayLayout}}"></bar-chart>
```

Maybe, since the variable substitution takes place in the client's browser, it doesn't matter. In which case I'll stop worrying about it :). It just seems like there ought to be a better way of passing the data to the directive "by reference", rather than "by value".

Comment: What is the format of the data? Wouldn't you just need to pass in arrays? Why would the attributes on the directive element scale with the size of the data?

Comment: The event system can allow you to pass data around without affecting the HTML markup.

Comment: Attributes are probably fine, but why does it sound like you have so many? Surely you can wrap them in an object or two?

Comment: If you pass an object using `{{ }}`, what you pass is a string containing the JSON representation of that object. Don't use `{{ }}`. Pass the object itself, using a isolate-scope binding using `=` or `<`. Of course, if you showed the code of the directive, it would be easier to help.

Comment: That's the solution I settled on, JB Nizet. I gave up on isolated bindings (i.e., those prefixed by '@') and passed the object, rather than the string it evaluated to. Doing that bollixed the directives $watchGroup, which previously focused on changes in that json string, so I also went with a $rootScope event to indicate when the data changed (the dataset is too complicated to create a simple $watch on the data itself).